# JS json. Отображение ссылок с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, json

Есть файл .json

```
{
"web_pages": [
   "https://www.cstj.qc.ca",
   "https://ccmt.cstj.qc.ca",
   "https://ccml.cstj.qc.ca"
    ],
  "name": "Cégep de Saint-Jérôme",
  "country": "Canada"
  },
```

Нужно вывести все ссылки , которые есть в массиве "web_pages". Но не li, а именно а с href. Просто заменив li на а выводится только первая ссылка.
Есть такой js

```
 let myList = document.createElement('ul');
 let webPages = member[i].web_pages;
 for (let j = 0; j < webPages.length; j++) {
 let listItem = document.createElement('li');
 listItem.textContent = webPages[j];
 myList.appendChild(listItem);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let test = {
"web_pages": [
   "https://www.cstj.qc.ca",
   "https://ccmt.cstj.qc.ca",
   "https://ccml.cstj.qc.ca"
    ],
  "name": "Cégep de Saint-Jérôme",
  "country": "Canada"
  };


 let testDiv = document.getElementById('test');
 let webPages = test.web_pages;
 
 for (let j = 0; j < webPages.length; j++) {
    let href = document.createElement('a');
    href.setAttribute('href', webPages[j]);
    href.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    href.textContent = webPages[j];
    testDiv.appendChild(href);
 }
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```